# mongod.service: Failed at step USER spawning /usr/bin/mkdir: No such process

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu-16.04

I'm running ec2 instance of os Ubuntu 16.04.

I recently tried to upgrade my mongodb from 3.2 to 3.6.

And I tried to run `sudo service mongod start` and mongod service failed to start.

Below is the error message.

```
mongod.service - High-performance, schema-free document-oriented 

database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2018-03-05 05:48:12 UTC; 11s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 18587 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb (code=exited, status=217/USER)
 Main PID: 16567 (code=exited, status=100)

Mar 05 05:48:12 ip-172-31-18-34 systemd[1]: Starting High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database...
Mar 05 05:48:12 ip-172-31-18-34 systemd[18587]: mongod.service: Failed at step USER spawning /usr/bin/mkdir: No such proc
Mar 05 05:48:12 ip-172-31-18-34 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=217
Mar 05 05:48:12 ip-172-31-18-34 systemd[1]: Failed to start High-performance, schema-free document-oriented database.
Mar 05 05:48:12 ip-172-31-18-34 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Unit entered failed state.
Mar 05 05:48:12 ip-172-31-18-34 systemd[1]: mongod.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

And I never edited a single line of default `mongod.service` file.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

If you have just copied `mongod.service` file from somewhere you should edit `User` in `[Service]` section

Answer (score 2):

```
Changing ownership of "/var/lib/mongodb" directory worked for me
Command to change ownership:
"sudo chown -R mongodb:mongodb /var/lib/mongodb"
```

---

```
**Old response:**
$ sudo systemctl status mongodb
● mongodb.service - MongoDB Database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2019-07-31 18:52:49 IST; 17h ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Main PID: 13728 (code=exited, status=217/USER)

Jul 31 18:52:49 LAP-LIN-712 systemd[1]: Started MongoDB Database.
Jul 31 18:52:49 LAP-LIN-712 systemd[13728]: mongodb.service: Failed to determine user credentials: No such process
Jul 31 18:52:49 LAP-LIN-712 systemd[13728]: mongodb.service: Failed at step USER spawning /usr/bin/mongod: No such process
Jul 31 18:52:49 LAP-LIN-712 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=217/USER
Jul 31 18:52:49 LAP-LIN-712 systemd[1]: mongodb.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.

**New Response:**
$ sudo systemctl status mongodb
● mongodb.service - MongoDB Database
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/mongodb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-08-01 11:54:10 IST; 8s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
 Main PID: 8143 (mongod)
    Tasks: 20 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mongodb.service
           └─8143 /usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf
```

Comment: Hi @Anju, explain what your code do to help other user to understand. Thank you!

Comment: There is no code in this just I have run Linux command "chmod" to change the permission of mongodb directory

Answer (score 0):

`/usr/bin/mongod - No such process.`  ---> This error means you have placed the mongod binary in someother path instead of the default one. Try changing the path in mongod.service file and reattempt it using `service start mongodb`

Answer (score -1):

For me it was solved by commenting "User" and "Group" directives in the service file as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48065475/systemctl-failed-at-step-group-spawning).
I hope it helps somebody.

Comment: That makes the service run as root which can cause problems including incorrect file ownership and running code with elevated privileges which can make security vulnerability much worse.

Comment: I see the process running as a non root user though.

Comment: There's a comment in the link I shared that states it behaves in the same way.
Yet, I might not be getting your point.
But I think that the process running as a non root process in my case rules out any security issue.
Thanks for your input anyway.